# Azure Synapse Notebook Read Variable

Tags: azure, azure-synapse, spark-notebook

I have a vary simple/toy pipeline where I have a pyspark notebook that has an exit value, a set variable activity set to the exit value and a second notebook that is parameterized with the variable.  It looks like the below.

[image]

I successfully set the variable, but I cannot seem to read this variable into the `input_values` notebook.  The notebook looks like the below, also quite simple.

[image]

My pipeline parameters then look like the below.  However my exit value just comes out as "hello "

[image]

I have also tried accessing the variable directly in the notebook (without parametrization) by `f"hello {@variables("my_message")}"`, but this resulted in an error.  When I try to look at documentation for this type of behavior it generally points to calling a notebook from another notebook so caller/callee notebooks, such as the examples from [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/notebooks/notebook-workflows).  This seems to be backwards for creating a DAG, so I do not want to do that.  What I want to do seems possible and I saw an example of something similar [here](https://medium.com/@joshylchen/parameterizing-dynamic-variables-in-azure-synapse-pipeline-2b06873462fe), but I can't seem to get it to work.

Can anyone point me to documentation that would explain how to accomplish what I want or is there something in the above that I am missing?

### Edit:

I tried to set the`msg` parameter to `@activity('exit_values').output.status.Output.result.exitValue`, which is what I successfully set the `my_message` variable to and that did not work either.

### Success

I don't feel very smart, but I will leave this up for anyone else that might be in the same position.  I was setting my `msg` parameter on the pipeline, not the individual notebook.  I successfully ran it by setting the parameter on the notebook.

Answer (score 0):

> I successfully ran it by setting the parameter on the notebook.

It is the correct way to pass the values to the Notebook parameters.

In the above the  `@variables('msg_var')` is a should be given to in a dyamic content and not in default value. The pipeline parameters do not support dynamic content here.

[image]

Also, we have to give the value of the Notebook pipeline in Base parameters of Notebook activity by creating a parameter with same name as that.

Here, it supports dynamic content, so give the variable like below.

[image]

**Notebook output:**

[image]